# Cannot install packages because "stringi cannot be built. Check your complier flags"

Tags: r, linux, installation, package, stringi

No matter what packages I try to install, it does not work. Tidyverse, ggplot2, dplyr. Nothing works. After looking through the long lists of error messages, I got to the root of the problem.

> *** stringi cannot be built. Check your compiler flags (Makeconf, Makevars, etc.).
>
> *** also, verify your C++ compiler's abilities (long long, STL, etc. support)

I have no idea what this means. I googled the message, but I couldn't find anything that helped. Can anyone help?

If it matters, I am using Linux Mint 18 and RStudio 1.2.1578.

Comment: What happens when you just run this: `install.packages("stringi")`

Comment: I still get the same message.

Comment: You could try to download a slightly older version of the "stringi" package that does not need to be compiled.

Comment: I am sorry, but this whole situation is more than a little beyond me. How do I find a version that does not need to be compiled?

Comment: How do I tell if it needs to be compiled?